# Is it possible to simulate a failure of an NUnit test without modifying the code of every test and/or fixture?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I would like to be able to simulate a failure of an arbitrary test in order to check that my TearDown logic works correctly. A unit test on a unit test, if you please.

But really, I have TearDown in some fixtures that produces attachments on failures. I must be able to show off this feature, but it is hard to produce a failure when you most need it.

So, I want to create a test parameter specifying the name of a test I wish to fail. Now, I can easily write an attribute implementing `IWrapTestMethod` or `IApplyToContext`, but then I need to apply it on every test method.

Is there a way to implement it without touching every test and/or fixture? By some kind of an assembly level attribute or assembly level setup method that would run before each and every test?

It is crucial that this logic would not prevent the `TearDown` methods from running, so `ITestAction` throwing an exception from `BeforeTest` does not fit the bill.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;
using NUnit.Framework.Internal;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: Common.EnableFailureSimulation]

namespace Common
{
    public class SimulateFailureMethodInfoWrapper : IMethodInfo
    {
        private readonly IMethodInfo m_mi;

        public SimulateFailureMethodInfoWrapper(IMethodInfo mi)
        {
            m_mi = mi;
        }

        public ITypeInfo TypeInfo => m_mi.TypeInfo;

        public MethodInfo MethodInfo => m_mi.MethodInfo;

        public string Name => m_mi.Name;

        public bool IsAbstract => m_mi.IsAbstract;

        public bool IsPublic => m_mi.IsPublic;

        public bool ContainsGenericParameters => m_mi.ContainsGenericParameters;

        public bool IsGenericMethod => m_mi.IsGenericMethod;

        public bool IsGenericMethodDefinition => m_mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition;

        public ITypeInfo ReturnType => m_mi.ReturnType;

        public T[] GetCustomAttributes<T>(bool inherit) where T : class => m_mi.GetCustomAttributes<T>(inherit);

        public Type[] GetGenericArguments() => m_mi.GetGenericArguments();

        public IParameterInfo[] GetParameters() => m_mi.GetParameters();

        public object Invoke(object fixture, params object[] args)
        {
            var res = m_mi.Invoke(fixture, args);
            Assert.Fail("Failure simulation");
            return res;
        }

        public bool IsDefined<T>(bool inherit) where T : class => m_mi.IsDefined<T>(inherit);

        public IMethodInfo MakeGenericMethod(params Type[] typeArguments) => m_mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeArguments);
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
    public class EnableFailureSimulationAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
    {
        private static string s_failTestMethod = GetParameterByName("!");

        public ActionTargets Targets => ActionTargets.Test;

        public void AfterTest(ITest test)
        {
        }

        public void BeforeTest(ITest test)
        {
            if (test.MethodName == s_failTestMethod && test is Test testImpl)
            {
                testImpl.Method = new SimulateFailureMethodInfoWrapper(testImpl.Method);
                s_failTestMethod = "!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to use `Moq` and mock the `IMethodInfo` interface instead of having the real `SimulateFailureMethodInfoWrapper` class.

Anyway, this seems to work perfectly.